# Typescript Extention or Inheritance with Enums (Enumerations)

Tags: typescript

I was wondering about enumerations that depend on each other, and if there is a pattern that doesn't involve gluing enumerations together with another type structure.

```
enum FruitEnum {
    Apple = "APPLE",
    Orange = "ORANGE"
}

// DesertEnum extends FruitEnum
enum DesertEnum {
    Apple = FruitEnum.Apple,
    Orange = FruitEnum.Orange,
    CheeseCake = "CHEESE_CAKE",
    ChocolateCake = "CHOCOLATE_CAKE",
    Pie = "PIE"
}

// CakeEnum inherits from DesertsEnum
enum CakeEnum {
    CheeseCake = DesertEnum.CheeseCake,
    ChocolateCake = DesertEnum.ChocolateCake
}

/*
    Type 'DesertEnum.Pie | CakeEnum' is not assignable to type 'DesertsEnum'.
    Type 'CakeEnum.CheeseCake' is not assignable to type 'DesertsEnum'.(2322)
*/
const whichCake: DesertEnum = Object.values(CakeEnum)
                                    .find(cake => cake === CakeEnum.ChocolateCake) ?? DesertEnum.Pie

/*
    Type 'FruitEnum | DesertsEnum.Pie' is not assignable to type 'DesertsEnum'.
    Type 'FruitEnum.Apple' is not assignable to type 'DesertsEnum'.(2322)
*/
const whichFruit: DesertEnum = Object.values(FruitEnum)
                                     .find(fruit => fruit === FruitEnum.Apple) ?? DesertEnum.Pie
```

I tried using types that combine everything, but it just seams like extra code that is error prone.

```
// This feels like a hack, it should be inferred by at least one of the patterns.
// If we were to add a new type of desert, it would be necessary to both create 
// the enumeration and add it to the DesertsType structure.

type DesertsType = FruitEnum | CakeEnum | DesertEnum
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not tied to using TypeScript's `enum` keyword specifically, you can create JavaScript objects that act practically identically to TypeScript enums by creating `as const` objects, and creating types for them with the same name using the `(typeof MyEnum)[keyof typeof MyEnum]` pattern. This creates the type as a string union, which allows TypeScript to figure out this sort of crossover.

Using JavaScript objects instead of TypeScript enums has a couple of advantages, though it's not all positive.

**+** The syntax is more familiar to JavaScript developers who are new to TypeScript

**+** The generated JavaScript is more obvious, because only TypeScript annotations are removed

**+** TypeScript won't generate reverse lookups for number enums, which can be unintuitive and cause unexpected problems

**-** TypeScript won't generate the type associated with an enum for you, so you need to create it yourself, making the code a bit more verbose

**-** Because the type is constructed as a union of constant types (e.g. `'a' | 'b'`), you may not get as useful autocomplete in your IDE because it will suggest those values directly rather than suggesting you access them through your enum object

---

In my opinion the upsides outweigh the downsides, so I use this approach in my own work, but also the differences are minor enough that it comes largely down to code style or personal preference. I think you've hit on one of the few instances where it actually makes a difference.

Here's your example, using custom enums with a utility `EnumTypeOf` type to make the custom type construction a bit more obvious:

```js
type EnumTypeOf<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = T[keyof T];

const FruitEnum = {
    Apple: "APPLE",
    Orange: "ORANGE"
} as const;
type FruitEnum = EnumTypeOf<typeof FruitEnum>;

// DesertEnum extends FruitEnum
const DesertEnum = {
    Apple: FruitEnum.Apple,
    Orange: FruitEnum.Orange,
    CheeseCake: "CHEESE_CAKE",
    ChocolateCake: "CHOCOLATE_CAKE",
    Pie: "PIE"
} as const;
type DesertEnum = EnumTypeOf<typeof DesertEnum>;

// CakeEnum inherits from DesertsEnum
const CakeEnum = {
    CheeseCake: DesertEnum.CheeseCake,
    ChocolateCake: DesertEnum.ChocolateCake
} as const;
type CakeEnum = EnumTypeOf<typeof CakeEnum>;


const whichCake: DesertEnum = (Object.values(CakeEnum))
                                    .find((cake) => cake === CakeEnum.ChocolateCake) ?? DesertEnum.Pie;

const whichFruit: DesertEnum = Object.values(FruitEnum)
                                     .find((fruit) => fruit === FruitEnum.Apple) ?? DesertEnum.Pie;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgVwLYBVwQPIDMA8KoQAewEcAJgM5QBKEAxgPYBOZOFwTAlnAOYA0UBHADWcBgHc4APilQAvFBQBtYRBAMsigLoBuAFB7GcdlABiTBJ2Dxk8qAG89UZ1ACCYMABsIALigAiVwAFIIAZGH8+JxcMJgBDXl8AjGpXADkAcQi9AF8oOKojdn1QSDMLKxskOyq0SGwcUogNcstrRCQpfT0Aeh6oABEICggmdtsiEnIqczaqwwZjYEHh0fHqhUcXNw9vP1nKjoA6dy8IKO3YhJ4kg-Wjq8SLlwBhAAsIVZe41T9-F4AEjAYABlGAAfRergA0hFns53gxGJ44iRvr8AoCMC8MKFXCgIVDYZFos4gpwkv4ggBJbJ5ApQIrAEroFYjMZVGodOqYXBNFpDdnrLoGPpQdEQTncD5cYBULBMBjVQVrCjzJnin6Sjp2LavD5fLV+FUc47vT4jCXw8VvJEMFFoo1stZVI6I5GoiAS3L5QqLYp6Jqa1SchS1dANfmaCVVEUGDXiN6cOhvCXG1am2wKAAUGAARgArejAI4ANzingQw2zMY6AEo66Tts2W622y4jlhuGRs9m6Fq6-JZP3VPI5Apa8g3baPY7VIOAPwL52ZpBHckQboJpMpu7poWhqD5ot0EvlyvVu5VRvt2931ud7u9hVtQdyWQvqxjhRX46nbyLsuJr3BuOhAA)