# Generic way to check whether a variable is part of an enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I know there are many questions about this. Still, none are trying to create a generic function, that receives an enum and a variable, checks whether the variable is part of that enum, and also sets the variable type if true.

I got this far:

```
// Function to check if the input is part of the enum
export function isEnumMember<T extends Record<string, K>, K>(value: unknown, enumType: T): value is K {
  return (Object.values(enumType) as Array<unknown>).includes(value);
}

// Usage:
if(isEnumMember(var1, WORK_TYPE_ENUM)) {
  // In here the type of var1 should be WORK_TYPE_ENUM
}
```

And it works, however, `var1` is still `unknown` or `string` or whatever its type was before the `if` statement.

If I change the return type to `T`, then it also doesn't work in this example (even when narrowing the enum to a string-valued one) ([link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/KYOwrgtgBA6g8gJQNIH0AqBNACgURTgOQFUBZKAbygEEoBeKAcioYBooAhOx9hqAXwBQAgPTCoAMTAgAxgBcAlgHsQUWYqjSAFsGkBrKPIBmq7QZAAHMLIMBnKOYCGAJ2uLjs06EgDgAD3OKLlCGUnJKKvI2OOAQJMAQAEbATgA8AlBQaFB%20sqAAJnYIOoF5KTayTvIgAOZsUrogigDuIAB8Aq0AFABuDgA2YMAAXFD1jS1sXhBoAJ7mw5kAlCO9A8C2mRTpUE7AsmBOKp1wCQBWOrIAdKuDNp1Ts-OLi5dV0gN5wHc3wIsA3AJBCIxEQbA5qsMBNJlOUoL0nABGEblSo1LhMBhCIxQTqRaKQOKJZI9ZwItjwZDobB4QikZ5bDLCABUTO2UCZmU0kSgeUUXxADGsTUCuhYbI5HnWsjm6zccNJGwYKKq1SgADJVDK5RTUJhcPhiCRWOKoA4QHkoE11hDrJLgoo%20n1mirsk4nIEhibHusGAADcy7QzyXwoAAk5GVaI10vm2sQuupBtIfF9vG5jWsDhsNnk1RADgSfSl6hjPoARAHgEGQ1Qy1AAD5QCuB4ModhlhiXToAJgAzN3u4sTeyxNtoSBYYZFIokVB-S2Q%20GdVT9bSSCmuPOq63w-CESmxzCHcBLk7qp0pzP-kJGWIYPIPCZ1pVqppbTKcTmIGA%20g5chamgfTQ5yzX1FigABaAxrF5L5LRFQ8J2sS9uxGLdqzDchlz1GlDQ3eh0J3cg91NOxsMTNcDwyccbGPU9FHPFDrz4IA)):

```
enum WORK_TYPE_ENUM { A = 'A', B = 'B' }

// Function to check if the input is part of the enum
export function isEnumMember<
  T extends Record<string, unknown>
>(value: unknown, enumType: T): value is T {
  return (Object.values(enumType)).includes(value);
}

// Usage:
const var1: string = 'A'

if (isEnumMember(var1, WORK_TYPE_ENUM)) {
  /**
   * This doesn't work,
   * the type of var1 is 'string & typeof WORK_TYPE_ENUM',
   * and we get the following error:
   * Type '`prefix_${string & typeof WORK_TYPE_ENUM}`' is not assignable to type '"prefix_A" | "prefix_B"'.(2322)
   *  */ 
  const foo1: `prefix_${WORK_TYPE_ENUM}` = `prefix_${var1}`
  console.log(foo1);

  // With the right type (simulated with `as`) - it does work
  const foo2: `prefix_${WORK_TYPE_ENUM}` = `prefix_${var1 as WORK_TYPE_ENUM}`
  console.log(foo2);
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA6g8gJQNIH0AqBNACgURTgOQFUBZKAbygEEoBeKAcioYBooAhOx9hqAXwBQA4AA8ADgHsATgBcoAMzAgAxjICWEkFDUBnHOAglgEAEbApAHhwA+ABQA3AIYAbMMABcUJQGsQEgO4gbKCQVFIA5p4IwMrSACYWOjJSaiDhUAA+UAZmUplQOgCephLObDYAlJ5OrsDaOlA4FAIAkFLAMmBSWrZwJgBWMTIAdDVuOrYhEGHhFVCODT5+gQDaALoVw6nKrnHAE2PAFQDcAoICAPQXUEQ6juEeArEgSVBOUgCMnkkpaVxMDCEankUFsun0kCMpnMDkcnzY8GQ6GweEIpAqc3IAigbzhH2OUCuUAsAFpYIhUJhcPhiCQzkCQWC9AYoblYfDyUiqajaRjmjiLgAqQXYnGCqBoAAWuig-mk3h0oqgguuouer3kEgkXygAAMxO15GoRCgACTkRGUlE00h8XVcfWG41m8jvD52+kCIA) work for you? If so, I can write up an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How enums work behind the scenes

When thinking about enum types, it's useful to consider how TypeScript transpiles enums declared with its `enum` keyword into JavaScript. For example:

```js
enum WORK_TYPE_ENUM { A = 'A', B = 'B' }
```

This becomes:

```js
var WORK_TYPE_ENUM;
(function (WORK_TYPE_ENUM) {
    WORK_TYPE_ENUM["A"] = "A";
    WORK_TYPE_ENUM["B"] = "B";
})(WORK_TYPE_ENUM || (WORK_TYPE_ENUM = {}))
```

That may be a little more complex than you were expecting, depending on whether or not you've run into this before. But in the end it becomes a plain JavaScript object that looks like this:

```js
var WORK_TYPE_ENUM = {
    A: 'A',
    B: 'B',
};
```

For this reason, it's useful to think of the types constructed when you use the `enum` keyword as a type of `Record`, where the values in that object are all the members of the enum and its keys are their names.

### A typeguard for enums

So, when you're trying to construct a type guard to check if a variable is a member of the enum, you need to define your typeguard so it's checking if the variable is one of the object's properties' values.

This is the approach I use in my own code:

```js
function isEnumMember<E>(
  value: unknown, enumArg: Record<string | number | symbol, E>
): value is E {
    return (Object.values(enumArg) as unknown[]).includes(value);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgUTCAtgWQKZYBGeATgDxoB8AFAFCKIBuAhgDYh4Bci4A1mHADuYADSI8mLAEESAc24AlPBDgkAJmRRQSMMLMQAfRJOIlDiFAE8icVmKq0AlNxbs8yFIjSIA3rQCQJHhQICRI1ADyhABWylAAdK4cKNQS2DKyjojMnnwCwgDaALqO8boQ7Gp4KUl4jgDctAC+tEA)

As you can see, the `is` keyword is used to refer to the `E` generic type, which is set up to refer to the values in the enum passed in to the function.

I've tested this function with the two cases you put forward in your question, and as far as I can tell it meets your needs in both of those cases:

```js
enum WORK_TYPE_ENUM { A = 'A', B = 'B' }

function isEnumMember<E>(
  value: unknown, enumArg: Record<string | number | symbol, E>
): value is E {
    return (Object.values(enumArg) as unknown[]).includes(value);
}

// Usage:
const var1: string = 'A'

if (isEnumMember(var1, WORK_TYPE_ENUM)) {
  var1; // <- WORK_TYPE_ENUM
}

if (isEnumMember(var1, WORK_TYPE_ENUM)) {
  const foo1: `prefix_${WORK_TYPE_ENUM}` = `prefix_${var1}` // <- "prefix_A" | "prefix_B"
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA6g8gJQNIH0AqBNACgURTgOQFUBZKAbygEEoBeKAcioYBooAhOx9hqAXwBQAgGZgQAYwAuASwD2IKNIDOOcBBLAIAI2AAnADw4AfAAoBUKADcAhgBswwAFxQxAaxCyA7iDahIVXQBzZwRgcVldABN9JUldaRBAqAAfKDUdXRSoJQBPbVlbNmMBAEpnG3tgRSUoHAoBAEhdYEkwXQUTOC0AKzDJADoKhyUTPwgAwJKoaxq3D28AbQBdEv6E8XtI4BGh4BKAbgFBAQB6E6giJWtApwFwkFira10ARmdY+MSuJgYhaWEoCZlKpIBptHoTDZXmx4Mh0Ng8IRSCUpuRzE9XvsoGcoPoALSwRCoTC4fDEEhHP4AoEqNRgjKQ54vGFE+GkpEkFH1Cz3R7CWSyN5QAAGAAdmsJpAAPFAAEnIsOJCLJpD4wq4Yol0rl5ChLzV2PO+KgACJxcBJTKqCasmatTL2CbKQIgA)

---

### The danger of number enums

Depending on how you use TypeScript's enums, it's possible you may run into some unexpected behaviour. If you use number enums, either by omitting the value of your enum's members so TypeScript can automatically assign them to integers, or by explicitly assigning them to integers, then you might notice that after checking the value of a variable with this function its type is wider than you expected:

```js
enum WORK_TYPE_ENUM { A, B }

function isEnumMember<E>(
  value: unknown, enumArg: Record<string | number | symbol, E>
): value is E {
    return (Object.values(enumArg) as unknown[]).includes(value);
}

declare const foo: unknown;

if (isEnumMember(foo, WORK_TYPE_ENUM)) {
  foo; // <- string | WORK_TYPE_ENUM
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA6g8gJQNIH0AqBNACgURTgOQFUBZKAbygEEAaKAISgF8AoFgMzBAGMAXASwD2IKPwDOOcBBLAIAI2AAnADw4AfAAoWUKADcAhgBswwAFxQuAaxCCA7iDqhIVRQHNzCYN0GKAJsrFeRX4QVygAHygpBUUIqDEAT3lBQzp1FgBKcwNjYFExKBwKFgBIRWBeMEURDTg5ACsvXgA6HJMxDScIF1cMqH0Cqxt7AG0AXQzmkO5jX2AOtuAMgG4WVhY5mf1yqG8QQKh2QUFzIbsQVZZ+digNcUlIGXklDSPBOnhkdGw8QlIMvrkbSHY7LKAAenBUGUAFp4kEQmFIp9UJhcPhiCQ1iwgA)

The reason for this is related to how TypeScript transpiles number enums into JavaScript:

```js
enum WORK_TYPE_ENUM { A, B }
```

Becomes:

```js
"use strict";
var WORK_TYPE_ENUM;
(function (WORK_TYPE_ENUM) {
    WORK_TYPE_ENUM[WORK_TYPE_ENUM["A"] = 0] = "A";
    WORK_TYPE_ENUM[WORK_TYPE_ENUM["B"] = 1] = "B";
})(WORK_TYPE_ENUM || (WORK_TYPE_ENUM = {}));
```

Again, that's a bit complex, but it ends up being an object that looks like this:

```js
var WORK_TYPE_ENUM_OBJ = {
  A: 0,
  [0]: 'A',
  B: 1,
  [1]: 'B',
};
```

TypeScript only inserts these reverse lookup properties in number enums, but it means not all the enum's members are the ones you defined - the type itself can also be indexed by `number` to get values of type `string`. So when we check that a variable is one of the enum's members, that includes potentially being a `string`.

You won't run into this problem if you only use string enums, always specifying members' values explicitly as strings as you've done in your example.

---

### A potential alternate approach to enums

If that drawback bothers you, there is another way to implement something nearly identical to an enum. There are few cases where the differences are meaningful, though [they do come up occasionally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76612600/1710523).

You may guess where this is going from where I talked earlier about treating an enum as a `Record`. You can define a plain old object using `as const`, and use it just like an enum. The main drawback is that TypeScript won't automatically construct a type for you, but that's quite easy to address. Here's an example:

```js
const WORK_TYPE_ENUM = {
    A: 'A',
    B: 'B',
} as const;
type WORK_TYPE_ENUM = EnumTypeOf<typeof WORK_TYPE_ENUM>;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=57#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgVwLYBVwQPIDMA8KB8UAvFCgNoDWEIA9lqQLoDcAsAFDsDGNcAzsFADqGAEoBpAPooAmgAUYEmADkAqgFliUAN7soeqAEEAXFADkB0wBpd+gEInTtq+wC+UAIa8o3PsFZtQSCFRSRl5RVUNEnhkNEhsHECIOmDxKTkFZXV8fyA)

If you export both the value and the type from your file, then you can import them in a single statement to use in another file just like an enum created with the `enum` keyword.

These approaches are similar enough that it largely comes down to personal code style. I don't mean to tell you that you should definitely use this rather than TypeScript's `enum` keyword, but I do think it's useful to at least know it's an option.

Here are the upsides and downsides, in my opinion, to this approach over `enum`:

**+** The syntax is more familiar to JavaScript developers who are new to TypeScript

**+** The generated JavaScript is more obvious, because only TypeScript annotations are removed

**+** TypeScript won't generate reverse lookups for number enums, which can be unintuitive and cause unexpected problems

**+** TypeScript won't treat anything with the type `number` as though it might be a member of a number enum

**+** There are some circumstances when using a union of constant types (e.g. `'a' | 'b'`) can be more versatile than a type created via the `enum` keyword, particularly when multiple enums share members.

**-** TypeScript won't generate the type associated with an enum for you, so you need to create it yourself, making the code a bit more verbose

**-** Because the type is constructed as a union of constant types (e.g. `'a' | 'b'`), you may not get as useful autocomplete in your IDE because it will suggest those values directly rather than suggesting you access them through your enum object

**-** You always need to specify a value for each key, whereas for numeric TypeScript enums you can omit the initialisers

Comment: You've nailed it! Thx man!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want `value is T` here since `T` is the actual enum.

For example:

```
// Function to check if the input is part of the enum
export function isEnumMember<
  T extends Record<string, unknown>
>(value: unknown, enumType: T): value is T {
  return (Object.values(enumType)).includes(value);
}
```

Which you would use like so:

```
// Usage:
const var1: number = 1

if (isEnumMember(var1, WORK_TYPE_ENUM)) {
  const foo: WORK_TYPE_ENUM = var1 // works
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/KYOwrgtgBA6g8gJQNIH0AqBNACgURTgOQFUBZKAbygEEoBeKARgBooAhOqAJigF8AoPgHpBUAGJgQAYwAuASwD2IKNPlRJAC2CSA1lFkAzZZr0gADmGl6AzlFMBDAE6X5h6cdCQ+wAB6n5TqH0JGQUlWSsccAgSYAgAI2AHAB4+KCg0KB9pUAATGwQtfxykq2kHWRAAcxYJbRB5AHcQAD4+ZoAKADc7ABswYAAuKFr6ppYPCDQAT1NB9IBKIe6+4Gt0ilSoB2BpMAcldrg4gCstaQA6Zf6rdonp2fn584rJPpzgG6vgeYBuPn4hCIiFY7JVBnxJIpSlBug4GEMogkHBwGAIDFB2uFIpAYvFEl1HMxYIhUJhcPhiCRHhs0pCQND9PJ5EN4Mh0Ng8IRSBxYQwoMIoA1-NorP8gA)

---

Important note: `Object.keys(MyEnum)` may not be what you want.

```
enum WORK_TYPE_ENUM { A = 1, B = 2 }
console.log(WORK_TYPE_ENUM)
/*
{
  "1": "A",
  "2": "B",
  "A": 1,
  "B": 2
} 
*/
console.log(Object.values(WORK_TYPE_ENUM)) //=> ["A", "B", 1, 2]
```

At runtime, there's no way to distinguish keys and values since it's just an object that maps one to the other.

Comment: thx for your response, I've already tried it before posting but forgot to note it. I've updated the original question, as comments are hard to edit.